# [Android]Sending parameter to a servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets, client-server

> Blockquote

I'm totally new to Client-Server programming and I'm having many issues.
I'm supposed to send a parameter from a client android app to a java servlet called "selector".
The servlet uses the getParameter method, obtains a variable under the name of "selector" and sends a series of JSONObjects to the Android client.
Unfortunately, my App keeps crashing.

This is my Servlet code

```
public class FeedServlet extends HttpServlet {
public URLGetter urlgetter;
public XMLParser xmlparser;
public URL page_url, page_feed;
public String siteName, selector, siteDescription;


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, NodeList nList)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //do nothing
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    selector=request.getParameter("selector");
    setWebSiteParam(request,response);//this method reads the selector and
                                      //chooses what to send back to the client
        try {
        xmlparser=new XMLParser(page_feed);//parses the RSS Feed the client requested
        NodeList nodeList=xmlparser.getNodeList();
        processRequest(request, response, nodeList);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FeedServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, NodeList nList)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String title,description,link;
    JSONObject dataObj=new JSONObject();
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            //Parsing the NodeList
            Node node=nList.item(i);
            Element nodeElement=(Element)node;
            title=nodeElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
            description=nodeElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent();
            link=nodeElement.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).getTextContent();
            description=lengthCorrector(description);
            dataObj.put("description", description);
            dataObj.put("title", title);
            dataObj.put("link",link);
            out.println(dataObj);
        }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FeedServletMobile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 }
}
```

And this is my Android Activity code

public class ShowNews extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_news);
    String buttonId = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("buttonId");
    String newsType = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("newsType");
    TextView textViewNews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    if (newsType != null) {
        textViewNews.setText(newsType);
    }
    TextView textViewFullcontent=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    Downloader download = new Downloader();
    download.execute(buttonId);

}
 private class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String request=params[0];
        String serverAddress = null;
        String myFeed="I failed";
        HttpsURLConnection conn=null;
        try {
            serverAddress = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/FeedServlet/FeedServletMobile?selector="+
                    request;
            URL url;
            url= new URL(serverAddress);
            conn= (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 );
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            String input;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
                myFeed+=input;
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        return myFeed;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        TextView textViewFullcontent=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textViewFullcontent.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Class Downloader is contained inside an Android Activity Class and once this Activity is opened, the app crashes right after the HttpsUrlConnection.open() method is called.

EDIT: The URLEncoder.encode method caused the crash, but still the App does nothing. 
I set the myFeed string with the sentence "I failed": the connection times out and the App prints "I failed" in my textView

Comment: dude, you should really post the Activity code, if it crashes when the activity is opened then start debugging from the onCreate() method, also, for requests from an Android device, I would use Retrofit2 or Volley, it's the better way to go and will save you some trouble and redundant code

Comment: I've added the whole Activity code @TommySM

Comment: Doinbackground can return null. Then string result in onpostexecute will be null. Check for null and do not use settext if so. But set a text saying so. You could better also return e.getMessage() from every catch block.